# Why is this formula involving the floor function not giving the results I expect?

Tags: c

This is math calculation that i need to program - define sequence a<sub>n</sub> as

- a<sub>1</sub> = 1
- a<sub>(n+1)</sub> = 1 / (2 × [a<sub>n</sub>] - a<sub>n</sub> + 1) where [x] is the [floor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/floor.html) function

If a<sub>2014</sub> = p/q, find `p + q`

And, this is the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {
   int n=1;
   double an=1.0;
   double an_floor=0.0;

   while (n<=2014) {
      an_floor = floor(an);
      an = 1 / (2*an_floor-an+1);
      n = n + 1;
   }

   printf("%lf", an);

   return 0;
}
```

Problems;

- I cannot compile (using web complier such as codepad, etc.)
- Don't know how to make result
- Fraction result is wrong

Comment: Recursion can be a better option here.

Comment: When we analyze it carefully, this is in fact an **excellent question**!

Answer (score 1):

For someone who always likes to remind people about floating point errors, I was caught asleep at the wheel in this case.

If you run the following program,

```
/* a1 = 1, a(n+1) = 1/(2*[an]-an+1) ([x] is floor function)
 * a2014 = p/q
 * find p+q
 */

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LAST_ELEMENT 2014

static double
next_element(double prev) {
    return 1.0 / (2.0 * floor(prev) - prev + 1.0);
}


int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    double last = 1.0;

    for (i = 0; i < LAST_ELEMENT; i += 1) {
        last = next_element( last );
    }

    printf("%g\n", last);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

you get this output:

```
C:\...\Temp> cl /fp:precise /O2 rrr.c
C:\...\Temp> rrr.exe
2.25
```

But, that is due to floating point error as [@JJoao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991627/jjoao) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30100335/100754). He outlines a specific way you can deal with this particular issue.

Another way is to utilize an arbitrary precision math library to help you. First, let's verify the issue using a quick Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( floor );

sub next_element { '1' / (('2' * floor($_[0])) - $_[0] + '1.0') }

sub main {
    my ($x, $n) = @_;
    $x = next_element( $x ) for 1 .. $n;
    printf("%g\n", $x);
}

main(1, 2014);
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl t.pl
2.25
```

Same as the C program.

Now, use Perl's [bignum](https://metacpan.org/pod/bignum):

```
C:\...\Temp> perl -Mbignum t.pl
5.83333
```

This increased accuracy comes at a performance cost. Without `bignum`, the script runs in 0.125 seconds with about 0.094 is spent doing other things than the calculation. With `bignum`, it takes about two seconds.

Now, modern C provides various facilities for manipulating how floating numbers are rounded. In this particular case, given the nature of the floor function, setting the rounding mode to [`FE_DOWNWARD`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/fenv.h.html) will fix the issue:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LAST_ELEMENT 2014

static double
next_element(double prev) {
    return 1.0 / (2.0 * floor(prev) - prev + 1.0);
}


int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    double last = 1.0;

    const int original_rounding = fegetround();
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);

    for (i = 0; i < LAST_ELEMENT; i += 1) {
        last = next_element(last);
    }

    fesetround(original_rounding);
    printf("%g\n", last);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> cl /O2 /fp:precise rrr.c            
/out:rrr.exe                                                           

C:\...\Temp> rrr                                 
5.83333
```

Comment: would it be `2.2518e+15`  = infinty?

Comment: **Very interesting!!!** 1) in unix I can not reproduce the behavior of the C version. (I get `2.5` (I dont know what the correspondent to `/fp:precise` option)

Comment: Hmmmm ... can you try adding `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to figure it for `gcc` when I get a chance.

Comment: replace   `FE_DOWNWARD` by `FE_UPWARD` and ti works! It is curious that we already lost 5 decimal digits in the result precision...
5.8333333333428480
5.83333

Comment: Sinan, it looks like "excess floating-point precision", "rounding" and similar are a difficult areas, (bugs, possible differences bw compilers, etc). In our problem: (1) `fesetround(FE_UPWARD)` fixes the floor problem (Excellent) - and probably with a minor increase of  the global final error (very minor problem). (2) `perl -Mbignum` works, and is a very clear and generic technique (Thank you for telling me about big* perl modules). (3) `perl -Mbigrat` works and is a no representation error solution.

Answer (score 1):

## This is a dangerous sequence:

floor(value with potential representation error) = Big errors!!

```
floor(3-epsilon)= 2
floor(3+epsilon)= 3
```

Big number of cumulative real number calculation = Big errors!!

## You need to study the numeric-precision errors!

using the OP code we get

```
1
0.5
2
0.333333
1.5
0.666667
3
0.5           <===== Big precision ERROR it should be 0.25
2
1
2.2518e+15A   <===== infinity
4.44089e-16   <===== zero
1
0.5
....(wrong) cyclic behavior
```

final (wrong!!) result = `2.2518e+15A   <===== infinity`

## Update: But what should we do?

1) `floor` problem: substitute `floor(x)` by `floor(x + 2*expectedError)`

2) about cumulative errors: Replace `double` representation by a `(v1:int, v2:int)` 
fraction representation.`An -> v1/v2`

```
newAn = newv1/newv2 =
      = 1 / (2 * flo(An) + 1 - An) =
      = 1 / (2 * flo(v1/v2) + 1 - v1/v2) =
      = ... =
      = v2 / ( 2 * v2 * flo(v1/v2) + v2 - v1)
```

This way

```
newv1 = v2
newv2 =  2 * v2 * flo(v1/v2) + v2 - v1
```

In C:

```
main() {
   int v1=1, v2=1, n=1, oldv1;
   double an_floor;

   while (n<=2014) {
     an_floor = floor((0.0+v1)/v2 + 0.0000000001);

     oldv1=v1;
     v1=v2;
     v2=an_floor * v2 * 2 + v2 - oldv1;
     n++;
     //  printf("%g\n", (0.0+v1)/v2);
  }

  printf("%d/%d=%g\n", v1, v2, (0.0+v1)/v2);   //      35/6=5.83333
}
```

\thanks{Sinan Ünür}

Comment: Please see my answer for an alternative fix.